# Value turns to 0 inside for loop in C

Tags: c

Okay, I'll put a section of my code below as I don't think the whole thing is necessary. But essentially I ask the user for a value, i scan this and allocate it to a temporary variable and then i want to fill an array with this value for every position in the array.

```
printf("Input a value for the spring constant of each Spring\n");
scanf("%lf", &ktmp);
    for(tmp=0; tmp<argc-1; tmp++)
    {
        k[tmp] = ktmp;
        printf("%lf\n", &k[tmp]);
    }
```

Just the clarify both k[] and ktmp have been defined as double type and k[tmp] has been set to a size of argc-1 through malloc.

Comment: Turn on warnings and remove the `&` in the printf.

Comment: Wow i feel stupid, don't know why i put that there. Thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

In printf you are printing address of k[tmp]

```
printf("%lf\n",&k[tmp]);
```

you should print value of k[tmp]

```
printf("%lf\n",k[tmp]);
```

Note: You should also check the `argc` value before malloc.

Answer (score 0):

`&k[tmp]` is the address of element `tmp` of array `k`.
Change

```
printf("%lf\n", &k[tmp]);  
                ^Remove the & operator
```

to

```
printf("%lf\n", k[tmp]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The expression `&k[tmp]` returns a *pointer* to element number `tmp` in the array `k`. A pointer whose bit-pattern will (most likely) not be the floating point number you expect, and in fact may not be a valid floating-point value at all.